# Python, improving for loop performance

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop

I have made a class called localSun. I've taken a simplified model of the Earth-Sun system and have tried to compute the altitude angle of the sun for any location on earth for any time. When I run the code for current time and check timeandddate it matches well. So it works.

But then I wanted to basically go through one year and store all the altitude angles into an array (numpy array) for a specific location and I went in 1 minutes intervals.

Here's my very first naive attempt which I'm fairly certain is not good for performance. I just wanted to test for performance anyways.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
...

...  
altitudes = np.zeros(int(year/60))

m = datetime(2018, 5, 29, 15, 21, 0)
for i in range(0, len(altitudes)):
    n = m + timedelta(minutes = i+1)
    nn = localSun(30, 0, n)

    altitudes[i] = nn.altitude() # .altitude() is a method in localSun
```

altitudes is the array to which I want to store all the altitudes and its size is 525969 which is basically the amount of minutes in a year.

The localSun() object takes 3 parameters: colatitude (30 deg), longitude (0 deg) and a datetime object which has the time from a bit over an hour ago (when this is posted)

So the question is: What would be a good efficient way of going through a year in 1 minute intervals and computing the altitude angle at that time because this seems rather slow. Should I use map to update the values of the altitude angle instead of a for loop. I presume I'll have to each time create a new localSun object too. Also it's probably bad to just create these variables n and nn all the time.

We can assume the localSun objects all methods work fine. I'm just asking what is an efficient way (if there is) of going through a year in 1 minute intervals and updating the array with the altitude. The code I have should reveal enough information.

I would want to perhaps even do this in just 1 second interval later so it would be great to know if there's an efficient way. I tried that but it takes very long with that if I use this code.

This piece of code took about a minute to do on a university computer which are quite fast as far as I know.

Greatly appreaciate if someone can answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if this is working code, consider posting it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The fellas over there would be glad to improve it

Comment: Since you are already using numpy, how about storing the dates in a numpy array so the loop can be vectorized?

Comment: I would consider making a constant/variable out of len(altitudes), that would slightly improve perfomance during iteration.
Although, why not `for i, j in enumerate(altitudes)` that would give you indices as well as altitude values.

Comment: Numpy can work directly with [datetimes and timedeltas](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html), so it's basically just down to if `localSun` can accept and return an array of datetimes rather than just a single value.

Comment: I think it largely depends on what `SolarSun` actually does. If you could make it work with datetime arrays you could vectorize the for loop. It's difficult to say more with just the code you shared

Comment: `int(year/60)` -> `year//60`

Comment: Base on the limited information on what localSun() does, I would assume it would perform some complex math calculation. My best bet would be to take the nn.altitude() value from the last iteration as hint and pass it into the a modified version of the localSun() function which could somehow leverage the value, since altitude won't change a lot in a minute right?

Comment: If you don't have control or access to the source of `localSun`. I'd say [this](https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy08osti/34302.pdf) is the definitive source for the equations to write your own function.

Comment: @Aaron. The first sentence reads "**I** have made a class called localSun". Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I hadn't even considered giving it an array of datetimes and then doing calculations. Yes, it will be quite trivial to give it an array of datetimes instead, I'll just have to modify the methods to calculate foreach and modify some local variables. 

.altitude() is as follows:

Calculate the dot product between the observers radial vector and the vector in the direction of the sun. Now that's trivial. But to obtain where the sun is to calculate where the earth is in its orbit and what orientation. That is simply by calculating where the earth is in it's orbit too.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has naitive `datetime` and `timedelta` [support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html) so you could take an approach like this:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2018,5,29,15,21,0)
end = datetime.datetime(2019,5,29,15,21,0)
n = np.arange(start, end, dtype='datetime64[m]') # [m] specifies the interval as minutes
altitudes = np.vectorize(lambda x, y, z: localSun(x, y, z).altitude())(30,0,n)
```

[np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is not fast at all, but gets this working until you can modify 'localSun' to work with arrays of datetimes.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are already using `numpy` you can go one step further with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). It has powerful date and time manipulation routines such as [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd


start = pd.Timestamp(year=2018, month=1, day=1)
stop = pd.Timestamp(year=2018, month=12, day=31)
dates = pd.date_range(start, stop, freq='min')
altitudes = localSun(30, 0, dates)
```

You would then need to adapt your `localSun` to work with an array of [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) rather than a single `datetime.datetime`.

Changing from minutes to seconds would then be as simple as changing `freq='min'` to `freq='S'`.

Comment: You don't need a whole nother library for this. numpy handles date ranges just fine. And until we know more about localSun, your answer doesn't really add anything useful.